# How to add a gray overlay on any View in a layout

Tags: android

I was wondering how to add a gray overlay to everything inside of a layout file in order to see everything inside the layout, but with this gray transparent overlay on.

I tried to make a `View` and set to it a `background` like `#80000000`, but it looks like this `View` **takes all the space** (I'm using a `LinearLayout` in fact).

Instead I want to have this **overlay above all the other Views**, but still want to be able to **see what's behind**.

Comment: You can use a `FrameLayout` and then add the view you described above along ith linear layout but, this will add a level of nesting to your layout

Comment: What do you mean by "this will add a level of nesting to your layout"? @Shaishav

Comment: I basically mean, use a `<FrameLayout>` as your root container. Add both your `<LinearLayout>` and the view to it. Hence, increased level of nesting.

Comment: And what's bad about nesting? @Shaishav

Comment: Oh..nesting is bad. Each level of nesting adds more headache to the layout manager (via increased measure calls). Some details about it is given here: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html

Comment: So what should I do if I'd like to add like a new "layer" above this layout? @Shaishav

Comment: Thats where you calculate the trade-off. The above method will work undoubtedly. Is your layout complex enough (i.e. already high level of nesting) that adding one more level will result in visible performance loss? (The answer to this question is mostly NO)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122222/discussion-between-fet-and-shaishav).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the ways you can achieve the effect is by using a `<FrameLayout>` container as your root. Within it you can add your current layout and the view with a background together. Here, the `view` should cover the entire screen. So, your layout will look something like:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Your current layout here -->

    <!-- View to cover your screen -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: @ReazMurshed Whats the issue?

Comment: I've added a button. It doesn't overlay the button.

Comment: @ReazMurshed If you're adding a new button in the above layout programatically, you need to also provide an index while adding, otherwise, it will be addded to the top

Comment: I'm not doing it programatically. Doing it from layout. The same layout you've given

Comment: @ReazMurshed Well, either give me more info about what you're exactly doing (mainly because the above is quite trivial) or ask a different question.